# plotting 3d graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

im ysing python 3.7 and i tried to creat a 3d graph but i cant see the graph . 
this is my code :

```
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
    fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()#creating a figure
    chart=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection="3d")
    X,Y,Z=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[2,5,3,8,9,5,6,1],[3,6,2,7,5,4,5,6]
    chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image]
 thanks :)

Comment: What editor are you using to write the code?

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve. Your input data look rather like [a line or a scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots). It would be good, if you edited your question to define the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you want to plot, but the z component of a wireframe must be two dimensional:

this shows a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
chart = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection="3d")
X, Y, Z = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
                    [2 ,5 ,3 ,8 ,9 ,5 ,6 ,1], 
                    np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 4, 5, 6]])])
chart.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If instead, you wanted to plot a curve:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
chart = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection="3d")
X, Y, Z = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
                    [2 ,5 ,3 ,8 ,9 ,5 ,6 ,1], 
                    [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 4, 5, 6]])
chart.plot(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't the problem. The OPs code works perfectly fine for me producing your second plot.

Comment: using `chart.plot_wireframe`, it did not work for me in jupyter notebook, so saying "This isn't the problem" is rather assertive! It is too often hard to say what the problem really is as matplotlib is rather capricious and depends on the editor, backend used, etc... @Bazingaa

Comment: The OP code worked for me in jupyter. Hmm complicated